# Configure cloud-controller.xml in Stratos

Tags: openstack, wso2-stratos

I have configure the cloud-controller.xml file before I start the stratos server in order to support OpenStack. The order of file given to me was  stratos-server/repository/conf/cloud-controller.xml.

But, there is no folder called stratos-server, but there are about 12 files in different folders. Can anyone help me to figure out which file I have to configure and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using Apache Stratos 4.0.0, which earlier was WSO2 Stratos.

If you're using stratos-installer[1], then you only need to provide the OpenStack details in INSTALL_DIR/stratos-installer/conf/setup.conf file. The installer will configure cloud-controller.xml along with the other files using the information given in the setup.conf file.

However, if you're just extracting the Stratos zip file and configuring the files, the the cloud-controller.xml is in EXTRACTED_LOCATION/repository/conf/ folder.

[1] - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/STRATOS/4.0.0+Automated+Product+Configuration

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to openstack and stratos. Can you help me to configure the cloud-controller.xml, I gave the security grou name and keypair but it throws an error called "Carbon Initilaization Failed"

Comment: If you open a new question, with the contents of the cloud-controller.xml I can check what is wrong. You can also refer to Stratos dev mailing list at stratos.apache.org.